# Disable caching on the client side in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

Can you disable caching on the client side in a HttpHandler but enabling it on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) ;
```